# Css child dom set width:100% with inline-flex parent dom

Tags: html, css

I used to thought `display:inline-flex` makes the flex-container display inline so it's width is determined by the flex-item's width, like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.p {
  width: 200px;
}
.c {
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-flex
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  <div class="c">
    <img src="https://iph.href.lu/500x100?text=500X100&fg=666666&bg=cccccc" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `div.c` which display as `inline-flex` has the same `width` with the image inside it .

But if I set image's width to `100%`, It seems to be a dilemma, because `width:100%` means child dom's width is the same as the parent dom, while the parent dom which set `display:inline-flex`  says it has the same width with child dom.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.p {
  width: 200px;
}
.c {
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
img {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  <div class="c">
    <img src="https://iph.href.lu/500x100?text=500X100&fg=666666&bg=cccccc" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

This time the image's width is the same as `div.p` which has the width `200px`.

I don't know why the image width is `200px`, could someone explain it ?

Comment: The duplicates may look complex at first glance but read them (even many times) to understand what's happening and how percentage works in general

Comment: think you didn't understand and need to be re -mad